# Find file in iOS Application

Tags: swift

I know my file is in data/Containers/Bundle/Application

I want to list it and try

```swift
let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask).first!

do {
    // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
    let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    print(directoryContents)

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

however I get the message:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Applications” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

So how can I list the files in by bundle?

Comment: I think `Bundle.main.bundleURL` parent directory  is what you are looking for

Comment: The link is not about listing the files in the bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your bundle url `Bundle.main.bundleURL`,  get its parent directory and list its contents:

```
extension URL {
    var parentDirectory: URL? {
        return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.parentDirectoryURLKey]))?.parentDirectory
    }
}
```

---

```
if let bundleDirectory = Bundle.main.bundleURL.parentDirectory {
    print(bundleDirectory)
    do {
        let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: bundleDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        print(directoryContents)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```